# Word not expanding into shell command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Can somebody help on this:

I'm want to execute some commands in shell script by reading them from another text file something like this:

command_file.txt contains :

```
EXECUTED_OK_$(date)
EXECUTED_OK_$(hostname)
```

shell script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

while read command
do
echo $command 
done < command_file.txt
```

---

My problem is, echo prints as it is text as in the command file.
How can I make it expand and print actual date and hostname.

For example
Expected output should be:

```
EXECUTED_OK_22-02-2010 11:10:10
EXECUTED_OK_localhost
```

But I'm getting:

```
EXECUTED_OK_$(date)
EXECUTED_OK_$(hostname)
```

Comment: Consider `envsubst` if it's available.

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is desired and to-spec. If data were expanded as code "behind your back", it would be basically impossible to write code handling untrusted data in bash.

Comment: (then again, you're basically *requesting that* your data be executed as code, which is exactly what `eval` is for. It's also a general bad idea and best avoided, but... well, it *is* what you're asking for).

Comment: @Charles Duffy If we consider a situation in which we have to create dynamic commands at runtime, it can be easier way rather then running individual commands and concatenating the final output.

Comment: ...but if you want the effect of `eval`, why aren't you actually *using* `eval`? It's bad practice, but that's because *the thing it accomplishes* (breaching the boundary between data and code) is bad practice. You're actively asking for that thing (to evaluate your data as code, trusting its contents to be safe to execute), so, well, might as well use it if you're really, *really* sure that's what you want.

Comment: @Charles Duffy that's why I'm now going for function approach, I thought there may be some workaround for this situation except eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whitelisting approach will not allow arbitrary code to be executed like `eval` does. If security is not an issue, you should stick with `eval`, as externals used in this example have many corner cases for which the substitution will not work as expected.

The program substitutes certain externals referenced in each command of your command file with their output before printing the command:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read command
do
    while read -a external ; do
        output=$( "${external[@]}" )
        command=$( sed "s/\$(${external})/${output}/g" <<< "$command" )
    done <<END
    date -R
    hostname
END
    echo "$command"
done < command_file.txt
```

To use more externals, you need to add them to the heredoc between `<<END` and `END`. I have added `-R` to `date` to showcase an external with arguments.

As it has been pointed out, no processing (e.g. quotes, substitutions) except word splitting will be done on the external commands (blanks can be escaped (`one\ two`) instead of quoting).

Comment: `$($anything)` is not fully equivalent to `$(eval "$anything")`; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: ...similarly, `read -a external` doesn't process quotes &c. the same way shell parsing does, so just cutting over to `"${external[@]}"` doesn't really fix the cases unquoted `$anything` gets wrong. (Try `touch 'hello world'` as an example case; quote-unaware string-splitting will have `touch` create two separate files, `'hello` and `world'`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, that would not have worked with arguments. I have modified my example to use an array.

Answer (score 1):

use `eval` to expand the variables and re-execute it.

```
$ foo='EXECUTED_OK_$(date)'
$ echo $foo
EXECUTED_OK_$(date)
$ eval "echo $foo"
EXECUTED_OK_Tue May 21 12:39:45 PDT 2019
```

EDIT: `eval` is powerful but can be dangerous; it's basically code injection.  Quoting the arguments is a good idea;   see the comments below for more explanation.

Comment: `eval "echo $foo"` is a bit less buggy (or at least, a bit less misleading about how it works). If you run `eval echo $foo` without the quotes when `foo='*'`, for example, you get the `*` replaced with a list of filenames **before** `eval` is run, making its behavior almost impossible to predict without knowledge of those names.

Comment: (If you have `foo='*'; eval echo $foo`, you'd better hope that nobody created a file with `touch '$(rm -rf ~)'`; whereas with `foo='*'; eval "echo $foo"`, the `*` is expanded *after* the `eval`, so filenames it expands to can't be executed as code).

Comment: BTW, see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) for a discussion of why it's a good idea to quote even in `echo "$foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `eval`, assuming you *trust* the input file

```
#!/bin/sh

while read command; do 
  eval "echo $command" 
done < command_file.txt
```